# My code shows a single result, but there should be 20 items

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests
from lxml import html

all_stocks = []
resp = requests.get(url='https://www.tickertape.in/screener/equity', headers={
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
})
print(resp)

tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.content)

stocks = tree.xpath("//div[@id='screener-table']/section[contains(@class,'d-flex-row relative')]")
for stock in stocks:
    s = {
        'name': stock.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'desktop--only pointer')]/text()")[0],
        'subsector': stock.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'ellipsis-container subindustry')]/span[contains(@class,'desktop--only')]/text()")[0],
        'marketcap': stock.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'mrktCapf-col ')]/span[contains(@class,'jsx-3425801674 data-cell screener-cell  desktop--only')]/text()")[0],
        'closeprice': stock.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'jsx-3425801674 data-cell screener-cell  desktop--only')]/text()")[0],
        'peratio': stock.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'jsx-1054294817 scroll-col data-col d-flex-col text-right apef-col last-col')]/span[contains(@class,'jsx-3425801674 data-cell screener-cell  desktop--only')]/text()")[0]
    }
    all_stocks.append(s)
print(all_stocks)
```

My code shows a single result, but there should be 20 items.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'placeofyourdrive\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.tickertape.in/screener/equity")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tooltip_highlighter > div > button.jsx-2679829868.jsx-2491292752.small.secondary.button-root')))
search_button.click()
time.sleep(3)
name = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.jsx-1054294817.data-cell.screener-cell.ellipsis.highlight-onhover')
subsector = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.jsx-3425801674.data-cell.screener-cell.ellipsis.desktop--only')
time.sleep(3)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#screener-table > section.jsx-1054294817.typography-body-regular-m.text-primary.col-container.d-flex-row.relative > div.jsx-1054294817.scroll-col.data-col.d-flex-col.text-right.apef-col.last-col")))
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
time.sleep(3)
data = (driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.jsx-1054294817.scroll-col.data-col.d-flex-col.text-right.lastPrice-col ').text.split("\n"))
peratio = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#screener-table > section.jsx-1054294817.typography-body-regular-m.text-primary.col-container.d-flex-row.relative > div.jsx-1054294817.scroll-col.data-col.d-flex-col.text-right.apef-col.last-col').text.split("\n")
time.sleep(1)
for n,s,d,p in zip(name,subsector,data,peratio):
    print(n.text)
    print(s.text)
    print(d)
    print(p)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you # your loop and the code below and just print stock, you will see that there is only one element in it, my advise would be to use css selector instead of Xpath as its suit better for these types of scrapping. Cause here you select only one element with the xpath (the one with the xpath associated), with selector it can retrieve many elements if they have the same structure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).